# Why does a simple fn.extend not work?

Tags: jquery

I'm sure this is something simple, but I'm missing it - why does the following inside of a `<script>` tag not work and pop up an alert?

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    sayHi: function () {
        alert('hello!');
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.sayHi();
});
```

Comment: you should use `jQuery.extend({
    sayHi: function () {
        alert('hello!');
    }
});` if you want to invoke it using jQuery reference as a static method, use `jQuery.fn.extend` if you want to use it as a plugin method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you set `jQuery.fn.sayHi`, not `jQuery.sayHi` (which is `undefined`, hence you get a runtime error).

Methods you set on `jQuery.fn` are available on selections (jQuery objects) only, not the `jQuery` function.

`jQuery('body').sayHi();` would work.

For more information about plugin development, see http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/.